# converting Datetime column to date-only by converting_dtype() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def read_csv():
    # Method to read the CSV file "Hospital_patients_datasets.csv" using pandas.
    
    file_path = "Hospital_patients_datasets.csv"
    # Returns: Pandas DataFrame containing the data from the CSV file.
    
    ds = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    
def converting_dtype():
    ds = read_csv()

    # Method to convert 'ScheduledDay' and 'AppointmentDay' columns to datetime objects.
    # Returns: DataFrame with 'ScheduledDay' and 'AppointmentDay' columns converted to datetime objects.

    ds['ScheduledDay'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['ScheduledDay'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').dt.date
    ds['AppointmentDay'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['AppointmentDay'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').dt.date
    return ds
```

Error:

```
 Running Test case
    ------------- Test Case Failed -------------
    Data type of column 'ScheduledDay' differs:
    Your output Datatype: object
    Expected output Datatype: datetime64[ns]
    
    Data type of column 'AppointmentDay' differs:
    Your output Datatype: object
    Expected output Datatype: datetime64[ns]
    
    Following rows do not match the expected rows:
    Data Differences:
```

I was trying to convert 2016-04-29T16:19:04Z to 2016-04-29. It throws an error indicating datatype is still as object.

Comment: your `read_csv` method doesn't return anything, thus `ds` is `None` in `converting_dtype`. Can you provide a reproducible example of the input?

Comment: AppointmentID       5642903
Gender                    F
ScheduledDay         2016-04-29T18:38:08Z
AppointmentDay    2016-04-29T00:00:00Z
Age                         62
Neighbourhood      JARDIM DA PENHA
Scholarship              0

Comment: to get 2016-04-29 from 2016-04-29T16:19:04Z, just split on 'T' and take the first element ?!

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything after reading `.csv`.
Here, is the updated code that might help you,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def read_csv():
    file_path = "Hospital_patients_datasets.csv"
    ds = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    return ds

def converting_dtype():
    ds = read_csv()
    
    ds['ScheduledDay'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['ScheduledDay'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
    ds['AppointmentDay'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['AppointmentDay'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
    
    return ds
```